# gnome classic terminal mouse double click selection

Tags: mouse, gnome-terminal

I am running ubuntu 12.04.5 lts.
When I do a mouse double click selection I would like to select only a current word. For example in a line like:

```
/home/xx/asdf
```

right now the whole line gets selected when I doulble click on "xx". Also in a line like:

```
 $asdf=
```

I would like to select the 1st five characters - include `$` in the selection. Right now it selects `asdf=` - 5 characters including the equal sign.

UPDATE:
The answer I accepted no longer works since Ubuntu 15 it seems.
The following answer works in Ubuntu18:

[Double click selection in Gnome Terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290544/double-click-selection-in-gnome-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `gnome-terminal`:

In the menu bar, under **Edit** : **Profile Preferences**, tab **General** you will find **Select-by-word chatacters**. If you want the terminal to consider `/` to be a word boundary for selection purposes, remove `/` from the list of characters.

Comment: worked like a charm. I accept.

Comment: looking for same solution for ios...

Comment: got it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909737/double-click-and-select-the-pathincluding-in-terminal-app

Comment: that setting is not on Ubuntu 16.04  Gnome Terminal 3.18.3

Answer (score 3):

In some cases `gnome-terminal` preferences doesn't have the select-by-word characters option. It still has the profile-ID you need for command-line configuration though: Obtain it in the edit -> profile preferences -> General tab on your profile.

use

```
dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
```

to check whether it works. If no output, then the profile-id is not b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9, copy pate the one from the preferences as descibed above.

then use:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.;?%&#_+@~·:$"'
```

with the correct profile-ID. Here I remove `/` and `=` from the list  but add `$` according to the OP's wish.

Note that you can still select a word which is split by this character, say `iceweasel/stable` : double-click on the first part, then hold the `shift` key and click on the second part.

Comment: "anymore" is a bit ambiguous.  The **select-by-word characters** option is still there in Gnome Terminal 2.31.3, which is on a RHEL 6.5 (Santiago) system running Gnome 2.28.2.  Additionally, `dconf` *isn't* on the system.

Answer (score 1):

The dconf approach no longer seems to work on ubuntu20 and maybe others. This worked for me:

```
UUID=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${UUID}/ word-char-exceptions '@ms "-/@_&.?"'
```

Comment: I had to copy from a working configuration, and one can use 'gsettings get ....' from the above for reference.