# GNOME terminal double click delimiters

Tags: gnome

In the string `filename1, filename2` I want to double click `filename1,` and have it not copy the comma. I tried to follow the instructions in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290545), but it did not work for me. Specifically, I tried:

```
$ pid=$(dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/default | tr -d "'")
$ dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$pid/word-char-exceptions                                                                           
@ms '-,.;?%&#_+@~·:='
$ dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$pid/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-.%_@~"'                                                           
$ dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$pid/word-char-exceptions                                                                           
@ms '-.%_@~'
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using GNOME Terminal 3.14.3 on Red Hat Enterprise 7.3.

Comment: On 3.36 and it still doesn't work. This makes me want to go back to xterm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setting only got introduced in gnome-terminal 3.16. There is no way of changing the word selection characters in 3.14.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730632#c49

Comment: Sadly this does not work now - tried on 3.36